# Why Can't I Centre-Align My Font Awesome Icons?

Tags: wordpress, menu, font-awesome

I've got 4 Font-Awesome icons in my Secondary Menu.

I'm trying to get the social icons to align in the centre. I have added them in the menu of Wordpress individually as custom links with the below:

Align centre is not making a difference.

I've added a class to the social icons in the Wordpress menu options, called 'socialiconmenu'.

I'm targeting that class in my CSS to try and center it, see below:

SOCIAL ICONS TOP MENU

.socialiconmenu {

```
width: 2.5vw;
height: 4vh;
background: #42187b;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
margin: 5px 5px;
display: block;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

I'm expecting this to move the social icons to the center, but they are not budging. What do now?

Comment: Need to see more of your code and if possible a working JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear and that's why It's tough to give you a proper solution.

You can use `text-align: left` instead of **float**. Or you should declare the **width** of the parent element and use **float**. It may work.

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim for your response, I'll try to clarify. I have added 4 social media icons to my Wordpress menu using Font Awesome and I am trying to edit their style by adding a custom class, however my CSS code is not changing them in an expected way. I have tried adding float and text align - neither of these have worked.

Comment: Can you provide me the Markup here?

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, I've updated the post with everything above. Hope you can help!